# NestJs Swagger mixed types

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, openapi

I have a class that one of the properties can be string or array of strings, not sure how should I define it in swagger

```
    @ApiProperty({
        description: `to email address`,
        type: ???, <- what should be here?
        required: true,
    })
    to: string | Array<string>;
```

I tried

```
    @ApiProperty({
        description: `to email address(es)`,
        additionalProperties: {
            oneOf: [
                { type: 'string' },
                { type: 'Array<string>' },
            ],
        },
        required: true,
    })
```

and

```
    @ApiProperty({
        description: `to email address(es)`,
        additionalProperties: {
            oneOf: [
                { type: 'string' },
                { type: 'string[]' },
            ],
        },
        required: true,
    })
```

and

```
    @ApiProperty({
        description: `to email address(es)`,
        additionalProperties: {
            oneOf: [
                { type: 'string' },
                { type: '[string]' },
            ],
        },
        required: true,
    })
```

but the result is like below image, which is not correct

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please try

```
@ApiProperty({
   oneOf: [
      { type: 'string' },
      { 
         type: 'array',
         items: {
            type: 'string'
         }
      }
   ]
})
```

`Array<TItem>` can be expressed in OpenAPI with `{type: 'array', items: { type: TItem } }`